# How to select rows while 2 columns not in all 2 other columns in the same table mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to get all rows from the table where `question_id <> target` and `question_type <> target_type` in all the rows

for example

```
+----+-------------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------+
| id | question_id | question_type | target_type | target | start |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------+
|  1 |           3 |             0 |           2 | 1      |     1 |
|  3 |           1 |             1 |           2 | 3      |     0 |
|  5 |           3 |             0 |           1 | 3      |     0 |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------+
```

my result should be second row with id 3

```
+----+-------------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------+
| id | question_id | question_type | target_type | target | start |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------+
|  3 |           1 |             1 |           2 | 3      |     0 |
```

I need to take both `question_id` and `question_type` in the first row and compare both of them with `target` and `target_type` in all rows
and get the row when `question_id` and `question_type` not equal to `target` and `target_type where start = 1` and `question_id` and `question_type when start = 1` won't appear in the results

as I have row 1 has `start = 1`, and its `question_id = 3` and `question_type = 0` so, I want to exclude any row with (`question_id = 3` and `question_type = 0`) from my result

and in row 2 : `question_id = 1` and `question_type = 1` doesn't equal `target` and `target_type` in all rows

Here's what I've tried:

```
SELECT s.* 
  FROM assign s 
  JOIN assign l1 
    ON s.question_id <> l1.target 
  JOIN assign l2 
    ON s.question_type <> l2.target_type
```

and

```
SELECT *  
  FROM assign` 
 WHERE (question_id NOT IN (SELECT target from assign) ) 
   AND question_type <> target_type 
   AND scenario_id = 3 
   AND start = 0
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried 2 ways 
1.inner join

`SELECT s.* FROM assign s
INNER JOIN assign l1
    ON s.question_id <> l1.target 
INNER JOIN assign l2
    ON s.question_type <> l2.target_type`


2. 
`SELECT * FROM `assign` WHERE (question_id NOT IN (SELECT target from assign) ) AND question_type <> target_type AND scenario_id = 3 AND start = 0`